# Graphite not graphing statsd requests

Tags: node.js, nginx, graphite

I've got graphite and statsd (nodejs 0.6.2) setup on a Ubuntu 11.04 running nginx 1.010 using uwsgi.

I can confirm that graphite is setup correctly as when I run the example python client it will being dropping data on the graph as it should. However, when I start statsd (it starts without error), and start my app that just loops and dumps stats I don't see any stats being graphed.

I've done tcpdump on port 8125 and I am seeing the request coming in. Any thoughts?

Comment: do you see the whisper data files being created? Look in /opt/graphite/storage/whisper (or something similar if you installed graphite elsewhere..). YOu should have a data file for every metric or timer you created. I believe statsd puts them in a subdir called "stats".

Answer (score 0):

1. |your script| -> |statsd:8125|

Edit the statsd config file and change the backend to 'console'. Now start statsd and your script in parallel. The statsd terminal will start dumping output. (The default flushInterval is 10000ms)

1. |statsd:8125| -> |carbon/whisper|

tailf the log files from "/opt/graphite/storage/log/carbon-cache/carbon-cache-a". The latest one would be: console.log, creates.log, listener.log, query.log. Out of these, "creates.log" will tell you about the .wsp files being created. Ensure that the files are being created. These files reside in: "/opt/graphite/storage/whisper/stats".

1. For more info on the schema and config of your data being stored in there, use whisper-dump.py to read the .wsp file.

**Sample output:**

Meta data:
  aggregation method: average
  max retention: 157784400
  xFilesFactor: 0.5

Archive 0 info:
  offset: 52
  seconds per point: 1
  points: 10080
  retention: 10080
  size: 120960

1. Now ensure that the statsd config specifies "localhost" and "2003" as the addr and port.
2. Open localhost in your browser. You should have graphite. Select your parameters from the tab on left. You should have your graphs.